# How do i set and use the id field in django model and template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I need to be able to access a self incrementing integer field for my model and use it in my template. Is there a way to do that?

My code accepts complaints from users so for each complaint I need the id to increment from 0,1,2,3,4, and so on and then I need to access these in the template to be able to use it accordingly

models.py:

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
   id = models.AutoField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
   reportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null = True, blank= False)
   eventdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
   event_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   device_problem = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   product_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
   exemption = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   patient_problem = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   event_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents', blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.reportnumber
```

forms.py:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
   input_type = 'date'

class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Complaint
       fields = '__all__'
       widgets = {
           'reportnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Report number'}),
           'event_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Event type'}),
           'eventdate': DateInput(),
           'device_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Device Problem'}),
           'event_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'height: 130px;width:760px'}),
           'manufacturer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Manufacturer Name'}),
           'product_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Product Code'}),
           'brand_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Brand Name'}),
           'exemption': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Exemption'}),
           'patient_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Patient Problem'}),
       } 
    
   def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(ComplaintForm, self).clean()
       reportnumber = cleaned_data.get('reportnumber')
       event_text = cleaned_data.get('event_text')
       if not reportnumber and not event_text:
           raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
       return cleaned_data
```

template:

```
{%for c in complaint %}
        <a href="new.html" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-{{c.id}}"> -> I need to access the id here for css purpose
                <p style="color: #D37A19; margin-left: -130px; margin-top: -5px;">Report number:</p>
                <p class="history-level-1">{{c.reportnumber}}</p>
                <p class="comp-title-1">{{c.event_type}}</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-1">{{c.event_text}}</p>
            </div>
        </a> {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

views.py:

```
def History(request):
  complaint_data = Complaint.objects.filter(user=request.user) 
  context = { 'complaint':complaint_data }
  return render(request, 'myHistory.html', context)
```

Comment: `{{ c.pk }}` or `{{ c.id }}`?

Comment: I tried using those but does not work

Comment: What does it show? Can you try printing int in a <p>

Comment: Can you show the code for the view which is used for rendering this form?

Comment: bot id and pk are automatically created by django models, if thats not working then you probably aren't passing the complaints to context

Comment: i tried to print it in <p> and 6 showed up. But I only have one complaint in the admin panel.

Comment: because, you might have deleted the other 5 instances.

Comment: Ohk, umm... how can I like set the id to 0 again when I delete one instance... do I have to make a custom id for that??

Comment: I also added in the views.py

Comment: I don't think that would be a good database design. In case a row or instance get deleted, you may have to update all other instances in the database. In case you want to keep a count of the number of complaints, you may just use `.count()` queryset` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need add a field in your example in your template use`forloop.counter` or `forloop.counter0`

```
{%for c in complaint %}
        <a href="new.html" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                <p style="color: #D37A19; margin-left: -130px; margin-top: -5px;">Report number:</p>
                <p class="history-level-1">{{c.reportnumber}}</p>
                <p class="comp-title-1">{{c.event_type}}</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-1">{{c.event_text}}</p>
            </div>
        </a> {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you so much!